# How to store the result of ‘ls’ in a variable, and cd into that variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to store the result of ls in a variable , then I want to cd into that variable.

I have script as follows.

```
Cd /home/dev/command
work_dir=$(ls -ltrd log$(date +%y%m%d)\* | tail -n 1)
echo $work_dir
cd “/home/dev/command/$work_dir”
```

It showing error like no such file or directory

How to CD into the directory which the ls command is showing

Comment: store the output of ls in variable a: `a=\`ls\`` then cd to this: `cd $a`

Comment: work_dir=$(ls -ltrd log$(date +%y%m%d)* | tail -n 1).          echo $work_dir                             cd “/home/dev/command/$work_dir”.              That is what i am doing right?

Comment: is the error something like `cd: drwxr-xr-x: No such file or directory`? What are you trying to do? `cd`ing in the last modified directory?

Comment: I am trying to do cd ing to the directory which this variable store $work_dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the unicode quotation marks mentioned in [perivesta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71765259/4957508), I'd also make some additional points:

- you appear to have capitalized the `cd` command in `Cd /home/dev/command`. Perhaps you're using a Windows-based environment (cygwin or WSL?)
- you escaped the `*` in `ls -ltrd log$(date +%y%m%d)\*`, which would be correct if your directory names actually ended in a literal asterisk, but an asterisk is often used as a wildcard to allow the substitution of any number of characters.
- parsing the output of `ls` is hard to do correctly, and even harder if you're asking for `ls -l` output, as [Fravadona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3387716/fravadona) hinted at in their comment!

Since you appear to want the most recent directory that matches a particular pattern, I would recommend using a UNIX shell that can sort by modification date natively, such as zsh.

```sh
$ zsh
$ cd /home/dev/command
$ cd log$(date +%y%m%d)*(om[1])
```

After changing to the right directory, this asks zsh to change to the directory that matches the wildcard `log$(date +y%m%d)*` sorted by modification date (newest first) with `(om)`, picking the first (newest) item from that list with `[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd “/home/dev/command/$work_dir”
```

You're using the unicode `“ U+201C` and `” U+201D` left and right double quotation marks, which are used in english text instead of the plain `" U+0022` quotation mark. So bash thinks the quotations are part of the directory name.

Comment: is it work after avoiding the  quotation mark